# Sum of n sums, Permutations of the indices, how to write them in Mathematica?

Tags: summation, scoping, permutation

I was wondering how  to write a function $ F (r, q, n, f) $ in Mathematica, defined in this way:

$$F(r,q,n,f):=\sum_{i_0=1}^q f(i_0) \Biggl(\sum_{i_1=i_0+1}^{q+1} f(i_1)\biggl(\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^{q+2} f(i_2)\Bigl(\ldots(\sum_{i_n=i_{n-1}+1}^{q+n} f(i_n))\ldots \Bigl) \biggl) \Biggl)$$ 
es.
$$ \sum_{i_0=1}^2 f(i_0) \Biggl(\sum_{i_1=i_0+1}^{3} f(i_1)\biggl(\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^{4} f(i_2) \biggl) \Biggl)=f(1)f(2)f(3)+f(1)f(2)f(4)+f(1)f(3)f(4)+ +f(2)f(3)f(4)$$

does an operator already exist that can be used in this way?

trying to write this function on mathematica I realized that the "recursion" is variable and I don't know how to program in this case.

thank you

$ \ $

$ \ $

further example

$$ \sum_{i_0=1}^1 f(i_0) \Biggl(\sum_{i_1=i_0+1}^{2} f(i_1)\biggl(\sum_{i_2=i_1+1}^{3} f(i_2)(\sum_{i_3=i_2+1}^{4} f(i_2)) \biggl) \Biggl)=f(1)f(2)f(3)f(4)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is already built-in as `SymmetricPolynomial[]`:

```
SymmetricPolynomial[3, Array[f, 4]]
   f[1] f[2] f[3] + f[1] f[2] f[4] + f[1] f[3] f[4] + f[2] f[3] f[4]

SymmetricPolynomial[4, Array[f, 4]]
   f[1] f[2] f[3] f[4]
```

but otherwise, Bill's suggestion can be vastly simplified using `Sum[]` and `Product[]`'s ability to take a list of indices:

```
Sum[Product[f[k], {k, idx}], {idx, Subsets[Range[4], {3}]}]
   f[1] f[2] f[3] + f[1] f[2] f[4] + f[1] f[3] f[4] + f[2] f[3] f[4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this

```
Total[Map[Times@@#&,Map[f,Subsets[{1,2,3,4},{3}],{-1}]]]
```

which gives you this

```
f[1]*f[2]*f[3] + f[1]*f[2]*f[4] + f[1]*f[3]*f[4] + f[2]*f[3]*f[4]
```

and this

```
Total[Map[Apply[Times,#]&,Map[f,Subsets[{1,2,3,4},{4}],{-1}]]]
```

which gives you this

```
f[1]*f[2]*f[3]*f[4]
```

That seems close to what you want to accomplish. All you have to do is see how to connect the parameters of your function F to the constants in those expressions.

If you look up Total and Map and Apply and Times and Subsets in the help system and study how those work I think you might be able to see how to do this and raise your programming skill to the next level in the process. I suggest you start with the innermost expressions first and after you understand those then add the next layer of expression and repeat until you understand the whole thing.

Comment: (+1)  You can shorten it to `Total@Subsets[Times @@ f /@ Range[4], {3}]`

Comment: @PatrickDanzi, very good point. I guess `Times` should be outside `Subsets` for the general case, e.g.,  `Total[Times @@@ Subsets[Map[f, Range[4], {-1}], {1}]]`

Comment: @kglr I have this problem if  i write "Total@Subsets[Times @@ f / @ Range [4], {2}]" I get   "f [1] f [2] + f [1] f [3] + f [ 2] f [3] + f [1] f [4] + f [2] f [4] + f [3] f [4] "   but if I define f as a fraction   "f[x _]: = a [x]/b[x]"   instead of getting   "(a [1] a [2]) / (b [1] b [2]) + (a [1] a [3]) / (b [1] b [3]) + (a [2] a [3]) / (b [2] b [3]) ..."  (which is good for me) I get   " a [1] a [2] + a [ 1] a [3] + ... + a [1] / b [1] + a [2] / b [1] + ... + 1 / (b [1] b [2]) + .. . + 1 / (b [1] b [3]) + ... "

Comment: @kglr great! thank you so much